# Looking for consumable data sets for Soccer (Football) statistics

Tags: data, sport

I'm looking for anything consumable that will go beyond just the results.  In an ideal world, it would have player statistics that include minutes played, duels won/lost, pass percentages, etc.  And game statistics possession, corner kicks won / converted, formations used, etc.  This is mostly to play with, and learn more about machine learning and data science, so the league represented is not as important as the dimensionality of the data.

I would also like to have a fairly rich American Football data set if anyone knows where I can find that.

Comment: Please note this site is about recommending *software,* not assets like howtos, manuals, [multi-media content](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/935/185). If you're looking for data, our sister-site [Open Data](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) might be worth checking with.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I had no idea Open Data even existed.

Comment: Too many SE sites to be aware of all of them :) But that's what "the community" is about: we combine our knowledge :) Good hunting!

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend [theScore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fivemobile.thescore) for Android.  It includes detailed statistics for each player as well as each team.  Possession statistics are also included as well as detailed game statistics.  Team standings within leagues are clearly presented.  The scope of covered leagues is global.